# Transposing matrix when differentiating it

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, partial-derivative, regression, matrix-equations

Hi so I am trying to understand the solution of linear regression with matrices (found at the following [link](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf)) and an confused about how on page 10 he says the derivative of $2Y'XB$ with respect to $B$ is $2X'Y$; I get that you drop the $B$ because it is a linear term, but why do you transpose the matrices $X$ and $Y$? Why wouldn't they just remain the same just like getting 5 after taking the derivative of $5x$?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The link above expired but I found this resource helpful. https://mahdi-roozbahani.github.io/CS46417641-fall2020/other/regression-cmu.pdf

Comment: @Learningstatsbyexample A snapshot of the PDF is saved at the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20170224003836/http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/OLSDerivation.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are being confused because he wrote every variable as a capital letter instead of the usual convention: matrices are capital, and vectors are lowercase. In your situation, $y$ is a column vector, $X$ is a matrix, $b$ is a column vector, and $e$ is a column vector.

Therefore you have:

$$e'e=y'y-2y'Xb+b'X'Xb$$

Taking the gradient with respect to all of the elements in the column vector $b$ (and if $b$ is a column vector, we usually assume that the gradient of any function $f(b)$ will also be a column vector):

$$\cfrac{d e'e}{db} = 0 - 2X'y + 2X'Xb$$

Note that if we do *not* take transpose of $y'X$, we will get a row vector and you would not be able to "add" the row vector and column vectors. Just to keep things consistent, we must transpose the vector $y'X$ to get all column vectors: $0$, $-2X'y$, and $2X'Xb$.

Answer (score 2):

It's because they don't only look for the derivative of the map $f:B\mapsto AB\in \mathbb R$, which is indeed just $A$; but rather for the gradient vector $\nabla f=\tfrac{df}{dB}$ such that $\forall H$,
$$
\langle\nabla f,H\rangle=df_B(H)=A(H)=AH=\langle A^T,H\rangle
.$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:b\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow 2y^TXb\in\mathbb{R}$ where $X\in M_{p,n},y\in\mathbb{R}^p$. $f$ is linear, then the derivative is $Df_b:h\in\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow 2y^TXh\in \mathbb{R}$; note that the matrix associated to $Df_b$ is a row. We consider the scalar product over $\mathbb{R}^n$: $(u,v)=u^Tv$. Then the  gradient $\nabla(f)$ is defined by: for every $h$, $(\nabla(f),h)=Df_b(h)$; that implies $\nabla(f)^Th=2y^TXh$ or $\nabla(f)=2X^Ty$.

EDIT. rych gave (before me) a good answer.